# How to install custom SQL for unmanaged model in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

A simple question, is there a way Django can install custom sql for model which is marked as unmanaged ?

I have defined the custom sql file and placed it in the required directory as django documentation stands:

> Django provides a hook for passing the database arbitrary SQL that’s executed just after the CREATE TABLE statements when you run migrate. You can use this hook to populate default records, or you could also create SQL functions, views, triggers, etc.
>
> The hook is simple: Django just looks for a file called sql/"modelname".sql, in your app directory, where "modelname" is the model’s name in lowercase.

src: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data

The problem is that it does not work when the model is marked with "managed = False".

As far as I am concerned the django just append the CREATE TABLE statement with the content from custom sql file. Which explain the behavior as the CREATE statement is not present.

But is there any way Django can execute my custom sql ?

My unmanaged model is a model for database view, which I try to create with this custom sql. And I want Django to run this sql automatically while running "manage.py migrate".

I am not interested in putting the sql code inside the migration file as it is quite long and I want to keep in in the sql file.

I am using Django 1.8.

Comment: As you can read in the documentation, this file won't be loaded if you use migrations. You can still keep a separate file with your SQL, but you need to manually add a migration that loads and executes that file.

Answer (score 0):

If you name your file correctly, it will be executed each time you run `manage.py syncdb`.

However, the naming of the file is a little tricky, and unclear from the documentation. For example, if you have an unmanaged model called MyModel in an app called MyApp running on MySQL, then you should have a file located in `myapp/sql/mymodel.mysql.sql`.

Also, if that file contains a SQL view, the view must be named with a format like `myapp_mymodel`.